# API Call- Statistics Sweden

Tags: python, json, api, pandas

I am trying to access the following API URL and convert it into a Pandas DataFrame:

http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/sv/ssd/START/BE/BE0101/BE0101A/BefolkningR1860

My goal is to read this JSON file into a pandas data frame and display years as index and the population of Sweden as values.

These are the values for each year:

```
- 2012: 9 555 893 
- 2013: 9 644 864
- 2014: 9 747 355
```

My solution looks like this so far:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/sv/ssd/START/BE/BE0101/BE0101A/BefolkningR1860'

df = pd.read_json(url)

print(df['variables'][3]['valueTexts'])
```

I have identified the years, but not sure how to access the values.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: I cannot find the values `893`, `864`, or `355` anywhere in that JSON file. Where are you getting these numbers from?

Comment: from here http://www.statistikdatabasen.scb.se/pxweb/sv/ssd/START__BE__BE0101__BE0101A/BefolkningR1860/table/tableViewLayout1/?rxid=cc7ba68f-ba0a-42c3-8c9c-d0bdf488c2d4