# API Call Statistics Sweden SCB, No values displayed

Tags: python, json, rest, economics

I am trying to access the values of the observations of my table, but I only see the dates in the JSON script generated.

Specifically, I am using this link

```
"http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/START/FM/FM5001/FM5001A/FM5001SDDSPM"
```

However, the same issue persists with other similar requests to the API.

For instance, this question has been asked four years ago sadly to no avail.

Please find below the link to the question with the same issue.
[API Call- Statistics Sweden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231815/api-call-statistics-sweden#)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick glance at [the docs](https://www.scb.se/en/services/oppna-data/api-for-the-statistical-database/), a `GET` only gives you metadata; to get the actual data you have to `POST` a JSON object containing a query.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I understood correctly, I have to make a POST request that contains a JSON query?

Comment: Yes. There is an example request on the page I linked to.